# Command menu in aptana studio 3 is not working in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, java, menu, window-manager, aptana-studio

The command menu of Aptana Studio 3 is not showing  in a Ubuntu 14.04.

[image]

Other menu items are working fine. Can anybody suggest a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issues here. Solved it by installing the Jave RE from Oracle. Downloaded the archive from the Oracle site and then followed the procedure as described below.

- Extract the folder from the archive.
- Copy the folder to `/opt/Oracle_Java/` (I had do create this folder).
- Run the following commands. (**Note**: Make sure to change the `VERSION` according to the version you download from Oracle).

  ```
  sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/opt/Oracle_Java/jre1.8.0_VERSION/bin/java" 1
  sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/opt/Oracle_Java/jre1.8.0_VERSION/bin/javaws" 1
  ```
- Then run these commands:

  ```
  sudo update-alternatives --set "java" "/opt/Oracle_Java/jre1.8.0_VERSION/bin/java"
  sudo update-alternatives --set "javaws" "/opt/Oracle_Java/jre1.8.0_VERSION/bin/javaws"
  ```

After installing Java, you can run Aptana.

You should start Aptana with `export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0`. I use a small script to start it (make sure to adapt the path):

```
#!/bin/bash
export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0
/path/to/Aptana_Studio_3/AptanaStudio3
```