# Why I obtain this error when I try to perform this simple bash script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, environment-variables, aptana-studio

I am following [this tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/a/501593/22949) to correctly execute Aptana Studio on my Ubuntu 14.04:

- [Command menu in aptana studio 3 is not working in ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488509/command-menu-in-aptana-studio-3-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04)

So I have installed the Oracle JRE and finnally I have create this `run.sh` file that have to execute Aptana:

```
!/bin/bash

export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 /home/andrea/Programmi/Aptana_Studio_3/AptanaStudio3
```

The problem is that when I try to execute this script with my shell I obtain the following error message:

```
andrea@andrea-virtual-machine:~/Programmi/Aptana_Studio_3$ sudo sh run.sh
run.sh: 1: run.sh: !/bin/bash: not found
run.sh: 3: export: /home/andrea/Programmi/Aptana_Studio_3/AptanaStudio3: bad variable name
```

Why? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Just add an 'Hash' (#) before `!/bin/bash`, so it must be `#!/bin/bash`, It's an convention. [This might help you!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967902/why-do-you-need-to-put-bin-bash-at-the-beginning-of-a-script-file)

Answer (score 12):

There are two errors. In short, this is the particular fix I would suggest (details follow):

```
#!/bin/sh
UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 /home/andrea/Programmi/Aptana_Studio_3/AptanaStudio3
```

#### Bad Hashbang Line

As [Shutupsquare says](https://askubuntu.com/a/506417/22949), your [hashbang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) ([technical details](https://askubuntu.com/questions/238002/is-bin-sh-read-by-the-interpreter)) should start with a `#!` rather than just `!`.

That is causing the first of your two error messages, and will prevent your script from being run as `./run.sh`, but is not the reason your script is failing to run `AptanaStudio3` (because the hashbang line is not required for `sh run.sh` calling syntax).

By the way, when you run `sh run.sh`, it runs your script with [`sh`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/sh.1.html) as the interpreter. But with the hashbang line `#!/bin/bash`, running `./run.sh` would run your script with [`bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/bash.1.html) as  the interpreter. This script does not in any way depend on the advanced features of `bash`, and while `bash`'s additional memory usage is almost certainly insignificant for this application, you may still wish to write the hashbang line so `./run.sh` runs the script with `sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

#### Incorrect Use of `export`

The main problem, which is causing your second error message and is the reason `AptanaStudio3` fails to run, is that you're using `export` incorrectly. The `export` command does not run commands. So your command is being interpreted as an environment variable itself.

- `export` can set and export an environment variable:

  ```
  export NAME=value
  ```
- `export` can also export an environment variable (with whatever its current value is):

  ```
  export NAME
  ```

`export` does *not* accept `NAME=value command` or `NAME command` syntax, however.

Assuming your goal is to run the command `/home/andrea/Programmi/Aptana_Studio_3/AptanaStudio3` with the `UBUNTU_MENUPROXY` variable defined and set to `0`, **you should just drop the word `export` altogether**:

```
UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 /home/andrea/Programmi/Aptana_Studio_3/AptanaStudio3
```

That is the standard way to run a command with a modified environment, from a shell.

The purpose of `export` is to export variables into the environments of all subsequently launched child processes (i.e., every command run from your script). So running `export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0` on its own line followed by the `AptanaStudio3` command, as [Shutupsquare suggests](https://askubuntu.com/a/506417/22949), will work, and have the same effect, and is a perfectly good and acceptable way to do it.

I prefer the way I've suggested above (*without* `export`) because:

- Semantically, your goal is not to export anything, but rather to run a *single* command with a modified environment. Using `export` may cause confusion to others reading your script (or to yourself later), and as a secondary consideration is arguably less elegant.
- With `export`, you need two commands; using the way without it, you need only one.

#### Optional reading: the `env` command works (sort of) the way you were trying to use `export`

Finally, there *is* a command that accepts `NAME=value command` syntax. This command is [`env`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/env.1.html). There's no reason to use it in this shell script--its function, in that basic usage, is to provide (part of) the power of a shell in running a command with a modified environment, and you already have that power.

However, under some circumstances, *outside* of shell scripting, you may find you need to set an environment variable for a command and run that command (and do those things in a single command). In contexts where just using the line `VARIABLE=value command` is not supported, you can use:

```
env VARIABLE=value command
```

You don't need that here though. All Bourne-style shells (e.g., `sh`, `dash`, `bash`, `ksh`, `zsh`) support `VARIABLE=value command`.

Answer (score 3):

Should be `#!/bin/bash`. I also think that you should have a newline at the end of `export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0`.

```
#!/bin/bash

export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 
/home/andrea/Programmi/Aptana_Studio_3/AptanaStudio3
```